# Remember jqGrid row position with sortableRows after page refresh

Tags: jqgrid

In jqGrid, one can set sortableRows to true to enable drag-and-drop row with local data. Is it possible to remember/persist row position even after a page refresh? I know it's possible to save column position with localStorage. How about the rows?